# .NET BlockingCollection All But One Thread Processes Messages

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, blockingcollection

I have a class that uses a blocking collection:

```
public class MessageQueue : IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<Message> queue;
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;
    private CancellationToken cancellationToken; 

    public MessageQueue(MessageHandler handler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.messageHandler = handler;
        this.cancellationToken = (cancellationToken != null) ? cancellationToken : new CancellationToken();

        for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DequeueMessage());
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(Message message)
    {
        queue.Add(message);
    }

    private void DequeueMessage()
    {
        Message message;

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (queue.TryTake(out message, 5000, cancellationToken))
            {
                messageHandler.Handle(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All looks good as far as all consumer threads correctly start dequeuing messages, messages are enqueued, and all threads take their first message off the queue and start processing.  However, only one thread continues processing messages after that.  All other threads seem to go off to the thread pool to do other stuff.  And I have a log in the dequeue method that would log a thread exiting that method--none of the threads log that.  I was not expecting this and I'm baffled. Is there a good explanation for this behavior that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Could `messageHandler` be throwing an exception? If it does then that would stop execution on that thread. Also, are your message handler and logging method thread safe?

Comment: oh crap, right on the money Scott!  Thanks a lot...wasn't seeing any errors in my log so assumed all was good.  But wrapping the call to Handle(message) in a try/catch now shows a System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal   Hmmm...now need to figure out what that's about :-)

Comment: You should probaby be using [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `DequeueMessage` rather than the way you are doing it now.

Comment: Matthew, I had tried that and was getting the same issue.  Or are you saying that GetConsumingEnumerable() is a better approach than TryTake()?

Comment: Yes, `GetConsumingEnumerable()` is the recommended approach.